# Node 14 + Jest + ESM leads to maximum call stack size error. Before it was unexpected token error. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have a backend project on Node js. Right now installed Node 14. So I have Jest and want to test functions from the `auth.js` file. So I create `auth.test.js` and `import login from '../auth.js` 0 got unexpected token error.

Then I do the trick with `esm` according to the [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling)

So I hade `"type":module"` in my `package.json` file, but it didn't provide any result.
So now I did this:

```
const esmImport = require('esm')(module);
const login = esmImport('../src/controllers/auth')(module);
test('Auth login', () => {
    let result = 'OK';
    expect(result).toBe('OK')
})
```

And the error is:

```
 FAIL  test/auth.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    D:\Programming\Anami\anami-backend\node_modules\wkx\lib\point.js:1
    RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Any help how to fix this issue?